# Power Query: Column of Tables (Data Extraction)

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

Problem: I am working with an oDATA API, and have extracted all the tables via PBI, but I have a column of tables and I do not know how to combine all the tables (they have the same fields). I need to combine or aggregate all the data (which is in the form of tables) from the Results column. Please see the photo for clarity.

[image: Column of Tables]

Does anyone know how to combine all of the data from these tables?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Table.Combine(
   {
    #"whatever that previous step was"[Results]
   }
)
```

Might not even need to wrap that `...[Results]` into a list. Try both.